# Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect

Tags: database, laravel

I'm quite new in laravel framework, and I'm from codeigniter.

I would like to add new key and value from database

```
static function m_get_promotion_banner(){
    $query = DB::table("promotion_banner")
        ->select('promotion_banner_id','promotion_link','about_promotion')
        ->where('promotion_active','1')
        ->get();
    if($query != null){
        foreach ($query as $key => $row){
            $query[$key]['promotion_image'] = URL::to('home/image/banner/'.$row['promotion_banner_id']);
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

That code was just changed from codeigniter to laravel, since in codeigniter there are no problems in passing a new key and value in `foreach` statement.

But, when I tried it in laravel, I got this following error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded element of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` has no effect

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-site\application\app\models\main\Main_home_m.php', 653, array('query' => object(Collection), 'row' => array('promotion_banner_id' => 1, 'promotion_link' => 'http://localhost/deal/home/voucher', 'about_promotion' => ''), 'key' => 0))

Comment: So, you want to update objects? Or do you want to add another filter to the query? Or do you want to insert a new row?

Comment: adding new key and new value @Jerodev

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The result of a Laravel query will always be [a Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections). To add a property to all the objects in this collection, you can use the [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map) function.

```
$query = $query->map(function ($object) {

    // Add the new property
    $object->promotion_image = URL::to('home/image/banner/' . $object->promotion_banner_id);

    // Return the new object
    return $object;

});
```

Also, you can get and set the properties using actual object properties and not array keys. This makes the code much more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

For others who needs a solution you can use jsonserialize method to modify the collection.
Such as:

```
$data = $data->jsonserialize();
//do your changes here now.
```

Comment: `jsonserialize()` solve the issue `Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\\Support\\Collection has no effect` +1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `get` is returning a `collection` of `stdObject`

Instead of adding the new field to the result of your query, modify the model of what you are returning.

So, assuming you have a PromotionBanner.php model file in your `app` directory, edit it and then add these 2 blocks of code:

```
protected $appends = array('promotionImage');
```

here you just added the custom field. Now you tell the model how to fill it:

```
public function getPromotionImageAttribute() {
    return (url('home/image/banner/'.$this->promotion_banner_id)); 
}
```

Now, you get your banners through your model:

```
static function m_get_promotion_banner(){
    return \App\PromotionBanner::where('promotion_active','1')->get();
}
```

Now you can access your `promotionImage` propierty in your result

P.D:
In the case you are NOT using a model... Well, just create the file app\PromotionImage.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class PromotionImage extends Model
{
    protected $appends = array('imageAttribute');
    protected $table = 'promotion_banner';    

    public function getPromotionImageAttribute() {
        return (url('home/image/banner/'.$this->promotion_banner_id)); 
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'promotion_banner_id','promotion_link','about_promotion','promotion_active'
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

just improving, in case you need to pass data inside the query

```
$url = 'home/image/banner/';
$query = $query->map(function ($object) use ($url) {

    // Add the new property
    $object->promotion_image = URL::to( $url . $object->promotion_banner_id);

   // Return the new object
   return $object;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this all evening, and I'm still not sure what my problem is.

I've used `->get()` to actually execute the query, and I've tried by `->toArray()` and `->jsonserialize()` on the data and it didn't fix the problem.

In the end, the work-around I found was this:

```
$task = Tasks::where("user_id", $userId)->first()->toArray();
$task = json_decode(json_encode($task), true);
$task["foo"] = "bar";
```

Using `json_encode` and then `json_decode` on it again freed it up from whatever was keeping me from editing it.

That's a hacky work-around at best, but if anyone else just needs to push past this problem and get on with their work, this might solve the problem for you.