# PHP + Laravel: Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I am trying to loop through some data, and if the key value pairs match a specific criteria within the same array I need to perform a calculation on all the numeric fields.

However, when I try to foreach through to the level I need, I get the error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect

Here is the data that I have:

```
{
    "CLIENT-NAME-1": {
        "returns": [
            {
                "valueType": "absolute return",
                "priceDate": "2021-05-31",
                "currency": "JPY",
                "quarterTDReturn": 260,
                "sinceInception": 0.58,
                "currencyType": "local",
                "returnMethod": "time-weighted",
                "grossOrNet": "gross"
            }
        ],
        "gainLoss": [
            {
                "valueType": "gain loss",
                "methodology": "Cumulative",
                "currency": "JPY",
                "fiscalYearToDate": 54584758,
                "currencyType": "local",
                "type": "total"
            }
        ]
    },
    "CLIENT-NAME-2": {
        "returns": [
            {
                "valueType": "absolute return",
                "priceDate": "2021-05-31",
                "currency": "JPY",
                "quarterTDReturn": 2.6e+94,
                "currencyType": "local",
                "returnMethod": "time-weighted",
                "grossOrNet": "gross"
            },
            {
                "valueType": "absolute return",
                "priceDate": "2020-09-30",
                "methodology": "IRR; Gross; Valuated",
                "currency": "USD",
                "sinceInception": 0.026000000000000002,
                "currencyType": "base",
                "returnMethod": "IRR",
                "grossOrNet": "gross",
                "authenticity": "valuated"
            },
            {
                "valueType": "absolute return",
                "priceDate": "2020-09-30",
                "methodology": "IRR; Net; Valuated",
                "currency": "USD",
                "sinceInception": 0.026000000000000002,
                "currencyType": "base",
                "returnMethod": "IRR",
                "grossOrNet": "net",
                "authenticity": "valuated"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried when I got the above error:

```
foreach ($this->data as $clientReference => $dataGroupsArrays) {
    foreach ($dataGroupsArrays['returns'] as $arrKey => $keyValuePair) {
        if (($keyValuePair['valueType'] == "absolute return") && ($keyValuePair['returnMethod'] == "time-weighted")) {
            foreach ($keyValuePair as $key => $value) {
                if(is_numeric($value)) {
                    $this->data[$clientReference][$arrKey][$key] = $value * 100;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I saw a similar question : [Indirect modification of overloaded element of Illuminate\Support\Collection has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539395/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-element-of-illuminate-support-collection-has) that suggested it is because it is a collection so I should map data instead

So I tried:

```
$this->data = $this->data->map(function ($clientReference, $dataGroupsArrays) {
    $dataGroupsArrays['returns'] = $dataGroupsArrays['returns']->map(function ($arrKey, $keyValuePair) {
        if (($keyValuePair['valueType'] == "absolute return") && ($keyValuePair['returnMethod'] == "time-weighted")) {
            
            $keyValuePair = $keyValuePair->map(function($key, $value) {
                if(is_numeric($value)) {
                    return $value * 100;
                }
            });
            
        
        }
    }
});
```

But then I get the error:

> Illegal string offset 'returns'

How do I loop through this data, and if `['valueType'] == "absolute return"` and `['returnMethod'] == "time-weighted"` multiply all the numeric valued in that array/object by 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps:

```
  $clients = $this->data();
    foreach ($clients as $cIndex => $client) {
        foreach ($client['returns'] as $rIndex => $return) {
            if ($return['valueType'] === "absolute return" &&  $return["returnMethod"] === "time-weighted") {
                foreach ($return as $key => $value) {
                    if (is_numeric($value)) {
                        $return[$key] = $value * 100;
                    }
                }
                $client['returns'][$rIndex] = $return;
            }
        }
        $clients[$cIndex] = $client;
    }
```

If you prefer to use map:

```
  $clients = collect($this->data())
        ->map(function ($client) {
            $client["returns"] = collect($client["returns"])
                ->map(function ($return) {
                    if ($return["valueType"] === "absolute return" && $return["returnMethod"] === "time-weighted") {
                        $return = collect($return)
                            ->map(function ($value) {
                                return is_numeric($value) ? $value * 100 : $value;
                            })->toArray();
                    }
                    return $return;
                })->toArray();
            return $client;
        })->toArray();
```

Comment: Good luck my friend.